# OS X Mavericks App Compatibility?

Tags: applications, macos, compatibility

Is there an efficient, quick way to check whether an OS X App is compatible with 10.9 Mavericks (rather than tediously going to each application developer's website) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**RoaringApps.com**](http://roaringapps.com) provides a compatibility list for multiple versions of OS X. You can search for an application by name or compatibility status, to quickly scan for apps that are known to be incompatible.

[image]
[image]

Apps can be [submitted by users](http://roaringapps.com/app/new), and also includes iOS compatibility if applicable.

[image]

You can also check for feature support, to see if apps contain the latest features available in the new OS, such as iCloud Keychain and App Nap.

[image]

Comment: Thats just too cool, it works for previous versions of OS X too !!