# Is there a way I can obtain Mavericks without having to download?

Tags: macos

My Wifi connection is not stable enough to be able to download 5.3 Gb. Is it possible to download from a thumb-drive? Does the Apple store sell Mavericks on a thumb-drive?

Comment: Please limit questions to one question per question. Here's an answer to your other question though: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106400/os-x-mavericks-app-compatibility/106402#106402

Comment: For me, this is just one question: how to get Mavericks if you can not download 5.3 Gb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can purchase directly from the apple store, If they don't have a physical Device to sell, you can take your device and get it upgraded for free.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest that you ask a friend with a fast internet connection to download it.

After the download has finished, just copy the installation file (you can find it in the Application folder) to your USB and then double click it at home.